# Code::Blocks building problem

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Hi I have a problem building a program in Code::Blocks.
The problem is when I build the code it starts giving me all kind of unrelated errors like these:

> main.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `system'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `system'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `ZSt4cout'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to 
>   `ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `ZSt3cin'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `ZNSirsERd'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `ZSt4cout'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc'
>
> main.cpp:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `ZNSolsEd'

....and so on

The problem is before I edit the same program in my Ubuntu 11.04 it was running without a problem on Windows 7. I just don't know any way to fix this. Any help is appreciated. Oh and if you want the code just ask me and I will post it. I don't do it now because this question is long enough.

Comment: maybe you forgot to specify the necessary libraries in your include path?

Comment: As @sled says, those are link errors.

Comment: What are the libs you're currently linking against?

Comment: i dont know doesn't it seems from the errors?

Comment: @Ikaros: Welcome to stackoverflow. If the answer below solves your problem, then you should accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the upvote/downvote number. This will mark the question as answered. I think it will also give you a couple of reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

a) more likely: you try to compile your project at a location shared between Win7 and Linux without `make clean`. The object files the compiler generates are different on each platform, thus you try to link with incompatible object files. Just do a `Rebuild all`.

b) less likely: the project might be set up as pure C, and you try to compile it as C++. Then, the correct decision would be to recreate the project correctly.

Comment: When you've made the wrong choice (C instead of C++) in the Code::Blocks startup wizard, you can still fixed it. You don't need to recreate the project (option b).  In the C::B "File" menu choose "Properties", tab "Advanced", change "Compiler variable" from "CC" to "GCC".

Comment: The other answer marked as a [duplicate] is not a question about Code::Blocks so not a duplicate. It is an IDE independent question, probably executed from the command line. How do we remove the [duplicate]-marking?